# Deciding priority in case of pair<int, int> inside priority_queue?

Tags: c++, std, priority-queue

If we are inserting a `pair<int, int>` in a `priority_queue`, then by which element will the priority be decided? Can we decide which element will decide the priority?

Comment: Can You explain a bit more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can provide your own comparator by using the `Compare` template parameter of the `priority_queue`. By default, `Compare` defaults to `std::less<T>` where `T` is the element type, which causes the `<` operator being called on the pairs, which is specialized as:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
bool operator<(const pair<T1, T2>& x, const pair<T1, T2>& y)
{ return x.first < y.first || (!(y.first < x.first) && x.second < y.second) }
```

Here's an example of how to use a different comparator:

```
#include <queue>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct CompareByFirst {
    constexpr bool operator()(pair<int, int> const & a,
                              pair<int, int> const & b) const noexcept
    { return a.first < b.first; }
};

int main() {
    priority_queue<pair<int, int>,
                   std::vector<pair<int, int> >,
                   CompareByFirst> myQueue;
}
```